# Conjuction of custom constraints

Tags: prolog, declarative-programming

I have defined some custom constraints like that:

```
constraint(a,something).
constraint(a,something1).
constraint(a,something2).
```

and i need this logical conjunction of them all as a result.
( if one constraint fails, the result should fail )

```
result(X) :-
    constraint(X,something),
    constraint(X,something1),
    constraint(X,somethingElse).
```

I'm looking for a more convenient way to avoid this explicit coding of all constraints.

```
result(X) :- ????
```

Comment: Predicates in prolog must start with a lower case letter. And the proper `if` operator is `:-` not `:=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some point, you need a predicate somewhere to actually list all the constraints you wish to apply. You could do something like this:

```
result(X) :-
    constraints(X, [something, something1, something2]).

constraints(X, [H|T]) :-
    constraint(X, H),
    constraints(X, T).
constraints(_, []).
```

This mechanism allows you to generate the constraints dynamically as a list, if desired. You could also have the list of constraints be a fact:

```
constraint_list(a, [something, something1, something2]).
```

And then use that in the `result` predicate:

```
result(X) :-
    constraint_list(X, List),
    constraints(X, List).
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider using `maplist/2`:

```
all_true(X) :- maplist(constraint(X), [something, something1, something2]).
```

Comment: Ah good one, mat (+1). Note to self: stop rewriting `maplist`. ;)